# How does clickonce installer installes prerequisites that are not mentioned on the prerequisites list

Tags: installation, directx, clickonce, directx-9, custom-installation

I want to package DirectX 9 with my installer as it is necessary for my software to work.

Can you please tell me how can i do that?

I tried doing this thing. I went to the heading under prerequisite tab, download prerequisites from the following location and pasted the url for DirectX, which is [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/7/9/B79FC9D7-47B8-48B7-A75E-101DEBEB5AB4/directx_aug2009_redist.exe).

When i published it, it gave me error:

> Cannot publish because a project failed to build.
>   Item 'Windows Installer 3.1' is required by '.NET Framework Client Profile', but was not included.

The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFx35Client\DotNetFx35ClientSetup.exe' in item '.NET Framework Client Profile' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.

I am working on my virtual machine which does not have .NET 3.5 so that my installer installs it itself if it's not in my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your workaround is failing because that URL is universal for all the prerequisites, not just one, and thus your *other* prerequisites are failing to load.

It looks like you need to add a custom prerequisite -- I've never had to do it myself, but  [instructions are here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx)